# Two way binding with custom expression?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, null, calendar, dbnull

I am using a gridview in my asp.net project to view and modify some records from the database. The database has two columns: start_date and end_date. When a new record is created these columns contains null, but they can be modified later using the gridview update command.

In gridview I have two template fields (having names start_date and end_date) in which I have placed two calendar controls. Upon clicking an update link of gridview it always returns an error because of the null value binding to the calendar. I have used this helper function to solve it:

```
protected DateTime ReplaceNull(Object param)
{
    if (param.Equals(DBNull.Value))
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
    else
    {
        return Convert.ToDateTime(param);
    }
}
```

and used these two custom expressions in calendar control's SelectedDate:

```
ReplaceNull(Eval("start_date"))
ReplaceNull(Eval("end_date"))
```

The problem is that two-way data binding the calendars upon selecting a date does not update the database table. Are there any workarounds? Or alternatively, a better solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you let them null when insert a new record , but many ways you can solve this problem i think .

**one of them** : in the `RowDataBound` event of the `Gridview`

```
 protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
               if (e.Row.Cells[1] == null) //the index of the start_date
                 {
                    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // in your case you will  make the selected date of the calender(through casting to calender) with the value you need.
                 }

            }
        }
```

**Or**: you can catch the exception , you meet in your Update button through

`try and catch block`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I think i did'nt explained you properly why its null in the start, actually I am working on project management system, in which a sales and support rep take jobs from client and creates a project in database as per details, then the project manager assign those projects to workers, workers daily check their sheet of projects and start working on them. so when a sales and support rep creates a project, start and end dates are null then once project manager assign them he sets those dates, if I use the code provided by you what binding should I use in calender control ?

Comment: Thanks,my code consider that the start and end date are stored directly in cells of the gridview, if you use template field as i expect and put your calender control in, then use an object data source as a data source or set the data source through the code behind then the bind will be `Binding expressions`.

look to this link::
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx.